# save wild-card in variable in shell script and evaluate/expand them at runtime

Tags: linux, shell, wildcard, expansion

I am having trouble running the script below (in Cygwin on win 7 mind you).
Lets call it "myscript.sh"
When I run it, the following is what I input:

yearmonth: 2011-03
daypattern: **2{5,6,7}**
logfilename: **error***
query: WARN

```
#! /bin/bash
yearmonth=''
daypattern=''
logfilename=''
sPath=''
q=''

echo -n "yearmonth: "
read yearmonth

echo -n "daypattern: "
read daypattern

echo -n "logfilename: "
read logfilename

echo -n "query: "
read q

cat "$yearmonth/$daypattern/$logfilename" | grep --color $q
```

The output I get is:

> cat: /2011-03/2{5,6,7}/error* No such
>   directory of file exists.

However, if I enter daypattern=25 OR daypattern=26 etc. the script will work.
Also, of course if I type the command in the shell itself, the wildcards are expanded as expected. 
But this is not what I want. 
I want to be able to PROMPT the user to enter the expressions as they need, and then later, in the script, execute these commands.

Any ideas how this can be possible?

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Don't quote the string (but this is a useless use of cat as the superior answer below from jabbie illustrates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `eval`, this should work for the {a,d} and * cases

```
  eval grep --color $q  ${yearmonth}/${daypattern}/${logfilename}
```

Comment: wow that was a very quick response! Thank you! and it WORKS~! this forum is great. It works, but I dont really understand HOW it works. Do you mind giving a quick explanation of how EVAL works and ${} in this case?

Comment: [This Unix & Linux Stack Exchange question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23111/4087) has more details about `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

Use quote to prevent wildcard expansion:

```
$ a="*.py"
$ echo $a
google.py pair.py recipe-523047-1.py
$ echo "$a"
*.py
```